# How to create a threshold in Observable Plot in JavaScript / TypeScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, visualization, grouped-bar-chart

I am trying to create a grouped bar chart using Observable's `Plot.plot` in JavaScript (code is in TypeScript).

The problem is that the x-axis is showing each specific date, however I want the dates to show dynamic months or weeks, not specific dates.

This is the code:

```
const chart = Plot.plot({
      x: { axis: null, domain: ["Add", "Remove"],  },
      y: { tickFormat: "s", label: "↑ Access Requests", grid: true },
      color: {
        legend: true,
        type: "categorical",
        domain: ["Add", "Remove"],
        range: redGreenColorRange,
      },
      style: {
        background: "transparent",
      },
      width: 1350,
      caption: "in 2 week increments",
      facet: {
        data: groupedAddRemove,
        label: "Created Date",
        x: "createdDate",
        // thresholds: d3.utcWeeks, 
        // ^ this doesn't work, but a similar structure has worked in other projects I've seen
      },
      marks: [
        Plot.barY(groupedAddRemove, {
          x: "type",
          y: "count",
          fill: "type",
        }),
        Plot.ruleY([0]),
      ],
    });
```

and this is what it looks like:

[image: Chart]

I want the x-axis marks to show a dynamic version of Months, like:

[image: X-Axis Example]

My data structure either could show the "Date" as a string, or a TypeScript typeof Date object

1. [data structure with date with a type of string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvosD.png)
2. [data structure with date with a type of Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jvvL.png)

This is the data structure type:
The 'groupedAddRemove' is an array of this type
( AddRemoveBarChartType[] )

```
type AddRemoveBarChartType = {
  createdDate: Date;
  count: number;
  type: "Add" | "Remove";
};
```

the "Type" can either be "Add" or "Remove". I had a boolean for this value previously, but  the "Add" and "Remove" fit better to automatically have the legend say "Add" and "Remove". It could be changed back to a boolean if there is a better way to display it that way.

The data could be changed in other ways too, if that will simplify things. I am also open to using a D3.js implementation instead of Plot.plot.

I'm very new to Observable Plot.plot so any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Why don't you share your notebook? That way we can fork it and test the solutions.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I'm not using a notebook, I'm writing the code locally